# Intersection of hypersurface and its hessian surface.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $f \in k[x_0, \dots, x_3]$ be a homogeneous cubic polynomial that defines a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$  and let $H(f) = \det \left[ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\right]_{ij}$ be the degree $4 \cdot (3-2)=4$ hessian hypersurface of $f$.
Is the number of intersections between $f$ and $H(f)$ non-zero?

If $H(f)$ is smooth and $H(f)$ and $f$ intersect transversely, then by Bezout's theorem we would get 12 intersection points, but I don't see why these conditions should hold.

The context of this question is Exercise 7.3(iv) of Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry by Reid, where we prove that a smooth cubic surface has a cuspidal cubic section.

Comment: Any two surfaces in $\mathbf P^3$ intersect in a set of dimension at least 1 (not a finite set of points).

Comment: @Art could you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer [Can two projective surfaces intersect in points only?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908373/can-two-projective-surfaces-intersect-in-points-only) a reference to Hartshorne is given, where it is proven that if two varieties have dimension $r,s$, then their intersection has dimension $\geq r+s -n$, and in addition if $r+s-n \geq 0$, then their intersection is non-empty.  Thus in this case $r = s = 2$ so the intersection dimension is at least $4-3 = 1$. 
So the intersection is non-empty.